# Make materials higher quality as the user gets closer

Tags: unity, textures, performance, tilemap, image

**Scenario**

I have a sphere with an low-quality earth texture on it. I also have a much higher quality earth texture (Gigabytes in size) that I can use but it's too performance intensive to use on most devices, especially mobile.

My current plan is to break the higher definition image into tiles (like how google maps does it) and load higher resolution tiles as the user zooms in.

**Question**

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your proposal sounds sensible, and as you point out has proven effectiveness in existing applications serving a similar domain. Is there a specific problem with this approach that you'd like answers here to focus on improving? Or is this solution already sufficient for your needs?

Comment: @DMGregory Good question. It's already implemented in prototype form but it seems antiquated. I like to think there's Unity features or plugins that would allow me to do something similar without have to rely on wrestling with hand-rolled map tiling. I'm hoping that reaching out to the broader community will result in a promising alternative.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Streaming Virtual Texturing](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/svt-streaming-virtual-texturing.html)? This is not supported on mobile, so rolling your own solution might be your best bet there.

Comment: SVT sounds very promising but since my imagery is already broken up into tiles I'm not sure how to leverage this. The [manual says](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/svt-how-it-works.html) that svt uses an async process and work in a separate thread to keep things smooth which is helpful as I'll likely follow Unity's direction.

Comment: @DMGregory MipMapStreaming looks like what I want BUT I'm working with a single object with a single material which renders MMS useless. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I went with a [slippy map](https://github.com/jderrough/UnitySlippyMap) and added the following

- A way to find which spherical tiles where in the cameras frustum view
- [A shader to render the 2d tiles as portions of a 3d sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70205085/332578)

[image: 3d earth from tiles]

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you may want to use the LOD system. It stands for level of detail. You can set different rendering qualities based on the distance you’re viewing it from. It’s really useful for rendering far away things with low quality/high performance while rendering close things with far more detail.